# Short-circuiting outcome

Tags: python, if-statement, pep

I came across the following statements from [PEP 532](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0532/):

- `__else__` is the short-circuiting outcome for `if` expressions due to
    the absence of a trailing `else` clause
- `__then__` is the short-circuiting outcome for `else` expressions due to
    the absence of a leading `if` clause

What is meant by those statements? Are there any examples that could clarify the points a bit more?

Comment: Keep reading the PEP you're reading (which you didn't link).

Comment: What do you mean by "from here"?

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/shortcircuit-operator.htm

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be reading (about) [PEP 532 - *A circuit breaking operator and protocol*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0532/), a proposal to give the *left-hand operand* access to a short-circuiting operation.

Python currently has no way to hook into the `or` and `and` boolean operators; these operators *short-circuit* in that if the outcome can be determined from the left-hand operand, then the right-hand operand expression doesn't need to be evaluated.

For example, the following expression won't raise an exception:

```
count = 0
average = count and total / count
```

even though the right-hand expression would raise a `ZeroDivisionError` exception if run.

The PEP proposes a new operator, the `else` operator, that'll let the class of the left-hand side handle the outcome of the operation based it's [truth-value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So in the expression

```
lefthand else righthand
```

the `lefthand` *class* is given access to either `lefthand` or `righthand` depending on the value of `bool(lefthand)`.

You didn't give the full context of the statements you found, but PEP 532 is the proposal that defines the `__else__` and `__then__` methods; `type(lefthand).__then__(lefthand)` is called when `lefthand` is considered true, otherwise `type(lefthand).__else__(righthand)` is called:

```
result = type(lefthand).__then__(lefthand) if lefthand else type(lefthand).__else__(lefthand, righthand)
```

You can implement these then as

```
class CircuitBreaker:
    def __bool__(self):
        # am I true or false?
        return someboolean

    def __then__(self):
        # I'm true, so return something here
        return self

    def __else__(self, righthand):
        # I'm false, the righthand has been evaluated and pass ed in
        return righthand
```

Note that PEP 532 is **still under discussion** and it may be that this proposal is never implemented.